# I saved a blob in oracle sql. I am unable to read it in R

Tags: r, oracle, shiny

I am able to successfully store it in the database but problem arises with reading the blob object. The error i am getting is  Warning: Error in unserialize: 'connection' must be a connection

```
    path <- file.path("io.pdf")
        browseURL(path)
        pdf <- readBin(con = path, what = raw(), n = file.info(path)$size)
    
        # Serialize raw pdf
        pdf_serialized <- serialize(pdf, NULL)
        df <- data.frame(pdfs = I(list(pdf_serialized)))
        conValidateUser <-
          dbConnect(drv = drv,
    
                    username = get_user(),
    
                    password = get_decrypted_pass(),
    
                    dbname = connect_string(),prefetch = FALSE,
    
                    bulk_read = 100000L, bulk_write = 100000L, stmt_cache = 0L, external_credentials = FALSE, sysdba = FALSE)
    
        QueryInsert_network_def <-
          paste(
            "INSERT INTO BLOB(IMAGE) VALUES (:1)"
          )
        dbGetQuery(conValidateUser, QueryInsert_network_def,df)
        dbGetQuery(conValidateUser,"COMMIT")
        # Read your table
        out <- dbReadTable(conValidateUser,"BLOB")
    
        print("hi1")
        pdf_out <- unserialize(out)
    
        #print(pdf_out)
        #print("hi")
        # Write the PDF in a temporary file
        tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".pdf")
        writeBin(object = pdf_out, con = tmp)
    
        # open it
        browseURL(tmp)
```

Comment: You've serialized PDF document, but try to deserialize the entire dataframe

Comment: But to read the blob(pdf) from the database don't i have to unserialise? I am new to this concept. Can I know what to change while reading this blob ?